# C language string append with dynamic memory allocation & file editing method

Tags: c, string

I have got a configuration file which is used for configuration of the program.
I would like to change configuration setting & its contents in the file when I receive JSON message related to the configuration setting. It is because when once the changed configuration setting resulting from JSON message returns all configuration file formed by JSON message.

For instance, when i received `"position" : "House 2 Temp"`, then parse this query's key and value, respectively.

And, using strcmp, compare key value into configuration file.
If matched string is found, write value from start of key and keysize+3 to size of value.
ex) strncpy(rett + key_size + 3, vale, sizeof(vale))

However, if JSON message is transmitted such as `"position" : "House"`, value is too short to substitute the value for position.

How can I do this?

I want to remove the value following key value in the configuration file for substitution of transmitted value.

a.cfg

```
version = 1000
num_sensor = 3
num_actuator = 1
op_mode = 0

name = CO2
id = 20170002
embedded = 0
mode = 2
interval = 2000 
reservation = 0
reserv_num = 0
enable = 1
type = 3
port = 0  
address = 20
offset = 0
interface = ANALOG
pin = 0
model_type = 21
timeout = 1000
voltage_level = 5
range_low = 0
range_high = 20000
resolution = 10
position = House 1 CO2
unit = degree
```

Comment: If this is in a file, then there's no way to go around rewriting the entire file if you are trying to insert more data than the file currently holds.

Comment: You could have a subdirectory called env/ and write or update to a file named position in there. Then send a SIGHUP to your process so it rereads the config file(s) in the environment directory. For example, you might want to read your primary configuration file first and then read any individual files later that show up in the subdirectory.